# Should users delete their answers with no upvotes?

Tags: discussion

Is it encouraged for users to delete answers with no upvotes, I understand we are encouraged to delete answers with negative votes by the reputation system, but what about answers with 0 votes? I suppose we should delete them whenever they are posted on a question that already has upvoted answers, and leave them up on unanswered question, is this correct?

Comment: Is the deletion for the sole purpose of there being no votes on the answer? That would not be good.

Comment: Nah. If you think they don't add anything to the other existing answers, go ahead and delete if you want. But don't delete them just because they got no votes.

Comment: I meant because they use space

Comment: If you take into account all answers that satisfy those requirements it might add up to something.

Comment: Most browsers have scroll-bars. Space isn't so much of a problem.

Comment: I meant space on servers.

Comment: I didn't know some browsers didn't have scroll-bars, how do they display big websites?

Comment: Deletion is soft-deletion, that doesn't save anything on the servers. The post is still there, it just won't be displayed to people with less than 10k rep.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense, when I delete stuff I just edit it out and swap the actual content with '{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}' though.

Comment: Why do that? The old version is still in the revision history. You *add* more information to be stored by making that edit.

Comment: @HDE226868 Oh, that makes sense.  I guess I won't delete then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, I advise against deleting answers merely based on their score. Even the automatic processes do not do that: they take other factors into consideration.

I have a few negatively scored answers (some at -4) that I wouldn't consider deleting; and a bunch of positively scored answers that I deleted. It depends on what's in the answer, and how it relates to the question and possibly other answers. Not the score.

Answer (score 0):

*"A critic is a man who knows the way but cannot drive the car"* - K.Tynan

So unless someone point out the fault in your answer, no votes or downvotes should not make you delete it. Sometimes I like to elaborate on answers from very basics which most people will avoid but it might help some "not so bright" student to understand it. It doesn't mean answer is bad, it is just for that person who after browsing internet for an hour will stumble upon my answer and will be satisfied.